# The choice of generators and the order of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Tags: group-theory

A group homomorphism $G \to G$ is fixed by its values on a set of generators of $G$.

Consider the order of the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Let $S = \{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$ be a minimal set of generators for $G$. Note that an isomorphism $G \to G$ sends a generator $s_i$ to  <strike>a generator $s_j$</strike>  of the same order.

Counting, per order $k$, the amount of generators $a_k$, we see that there is a total of $$T = \prod_k (a_k!)$$ possible isomorphisms. Namely, for $a_k$ generators of order $k$ we have $a_k!$ ways of permuting the the generators of order $k$ and thus $a_k!$ possible isomorphisms, which send generators to  <strike>generators</strike>  of the same order. To get the total number of isomorphisms we take the product of all the the possibilities.

> I want to show that the number of isomorphisms $T$ is independent of
>   the choice of generators for $G$.

This seems plausible since the order of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is not determined by the choice of generators for $G$.

**PS:** I raised this question on account of the homework question
$$\text{For two isomorphic groups } G \text{ and } G' \text{, prove that the amount of isomorphisms } \\ \ G \to G' \text{ is equal to the order of the group } \operatorname{Aut}(G) .$$

Comment: Note that an automorphism doesn't need to map all generators $s_j$ into $S$, consider e.g. the quaternion group with $S = \{i,j\}$, an automorphism can map for example $i$ to $k = i\cdot j \notin S$. Also, there may be relations among the generators that an automorphism must respect. The homework question can be answered much more easily by establishing a bijection.

Comment: In fact, the set of isomorphisms between $G$ and $G'$ is a principal homogeneous space for $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a group isomorphism $\phi:G\xrightarrow{\simeq}G^\prime$. Then $\phi$ induces a biiection between the set $\text{Iso}(G,G^\prime)$ of isomorphisms $G\xrightarrow{\simeq} G^\prime$ and the set $\text{Aut}(G)$ of automorphisms of $G$ given by:
$$\text{Iso}(G,G^\prime)\to\text{Aut}(G):\xi\mapsto\phi^{-1}\circ\xi$$
with inverse
$$\text{Aut}(G)\to\text{Iso}(G,G^\prime):\eta\mapsto\phi\circ\eta.$$

Comment: Can we define an identity element $e \in \operatorname{Iso}(G,G')$ such that $\operatorname{Iso}(G,G')$ becomes a group? Aside from the fact a bijection is sufficient in our case, instead of a group isomorfism $\operatorname{Iso}(G,G') \to \operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: @MusséRedi You can use this bijection to define a group structure on $\text{Iso}(G, G')$, in which case the identity is $\phi$. This group operation is not canonical, though.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein What is a non-canonical group operation?

Comment: Define $\xi_1 \cdot \xi_2$ by $\phi \circ [(\phi^{-1} \circ \xi_1)(\phi^{-1} \circ \xi_2)]$. Canonical is a somewhat vague term mathematicians use to say when a defined function/operation/etc. on an object doesn't depend on some arbitrary choice.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Could you point out the non-arbitrariness in our case?

Comment: It is arbitrary. It depended on the choice of $\phi$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Exactly. So our case is canonical now, because it indeed depends on some arbitrary choice, according to your stated definition of canonical.

Comment: You misread my definition.

Comment: Yes your right, our case is indeed non-canonical because it depends on an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Could you explain the moral behind canonical and non-canonical?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: In category theory you have this idea of naturalness and universality. Is canonical also in the same ballpark?

Comment: I prefer to just leave the term canonical somewhat vague. I'm sure there's a category theoretic claim that can be made that someone would claim is "precisely" what we mean when we say this is not canonical, but I'm not sure I buy that.